# Adding digits of an integer in C

Tags: c

My program asks the user to input an integer and adds the sum of the digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int inputNum, sum;

  // Gets the inputNum
  printf("Type in a positive integer, and this program\nwill calculate the sums of the digits: ");
  scanf("%i", &inputNum);

  do
  {
    sum += (inputNum % 10);
    inputNum /= 10;
  } while (inputNum != 0);

  printf("Your sum is: %i\n", sum);
}
```

But every time it put an integer in, I get a number around 36000. I saw another example online that used %d, so I tried it but it made no difference. Am I just going in the wrong direction from the start? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never initialized `sum`; it may well be starting with value `1,000,000`

Comment: If your compiler didn't warn you about your error, throw it away.

Comment: @n.m.: Some compilers don't perform the data flow analysis for initialization errors unless optimizations are also enabled.

Comment: Compiler still doesn't look good regardless, but it probably has a switch somewhere to perform more strict analysis.

Comment: @jxh yes. if you've got one of those, *throw it away*. you don"t have to use it to learn c. plenty of good ones out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized `sum`; it may well be starting with value 1,000,000

Just do:

```
int inputNum, sum = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, initialize sum to 0. Try then. `int sum = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Do it:

```
int inputNum, sum = 0;
```

i.e., you have to initialize `sum`.

Because in C the value of an uninitialized variable cannot be determinated.  The value that you are getting is garbage from memory.

Comment: Using `%i` is not an error. What made you believe that the OP did not want to take advantage of the capabilities of `%i` in `scanf`? As for `printf`: `%d` and `%i` are fully equivalent there.

Answer (score -1):

Initialize sum as zero. int variables don't have any default value unless its a global or static variable. as a (non-static) local variable inside of a function, it has an indeterminate value.